# Delete a user from azure active directory with Python

Tags: python, azure-active-directory

I have a task to delete a user/update user attributes in the azure active directory using Python.

I searched and couldn't find any solution to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To delete the user and update user attributes, you could call the Microsoft Graph API in python.

1.[Delete a user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-delete?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

```
DELETE https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user-id}
```

2.[Update user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

```
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me
Content-type: application/json

{
  "businessPhones": [
    "businessPhones-value"
  ],
  "officeLocation": "city-value"
}
```

To call Microsoft Graph in python, just refer to this [link](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-python-daemon), sample code [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-python-daemon/tree/master/1-Call-MsGraph-WithSecret#about-the-code).